# $.unique() is working properly in google chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox/ Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

The duplicate values in an array is removed by using  $.unique()  and used that array in a loop . In google chrome everything going smooth. But when coming into Mozilla and Edge unique is not performing its operation and getting the length of array as not expected

Comment: It works on my side. I guess your issue comes from somewhere else but hard to tell without seeing any relevant code replicating issue...

Comment: distinct_employee = $.unique(employee_list);

Comment: But is `employee_list` an array of DOM elements? Because this is this method's purpose to work only on this type of array otherwise it can return unexpected result

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Is this function from jQuery at all?

Comment: @Justinas I guess we are talking about [it](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)